# Could someone share practical example of RUs cost for aggregate within same partition?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to reason about what would be a realistic estimate of a cost for SUM aggregate within same logical partition that contains up to a few hundred thousands of documents each being up to 5kb size where query would do SUM of a single day data.

for example, a container has documents for lets say orders. each document has property `amount` and `date`.

i am wondering what might be the cost of query like:

`select SUM(c.amount) where c.date =someDate` ?
(again, all documents are in same logical partition)

could someone post a practial example?

Comment: The best way to check the cost is to generate some data that would mimic your expected data and try out queries on them like you would in your use case.
And... this question is not suitable for stack overflow.

Comment: @Omar Abdel Bari yes, i was afraid it might be the case but i wanted to cut a few corners. do you maybe have an idea about whats the easiesr way to generate that kind of a dataset in cosmos db? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [`CosmosDB RU calculator`](https://cosmos.azure.com/capacitycalculator/) for this case to get a rough estimation. Since you're about to perform [Point Reads](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/point-reads-versus-queries/) the RU charges will be minimal.

Regarding the sample dataset, download a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/toy-products-on-amazon) from Kaggle and insert to Cosmosdb using the [Data Migration Tool.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)

Comment: FYI this should be a comment, not an answer. There's just no way to know what the OP's RU cost will be until they run a query and examine the results. The calculator is certainly helpful, but... linking to a tool is not an answer. Same with linking to sample datasets.

Comment: Note that someone already commented the same thing, the day that question was posted: generate data and run some tests (and also pointed out that the question was off-topic). There's no need to answer, saying basically the same thing.